# How to extract coefficients outputs from a linear regression with loop

Tags: r, loops, regression, linear-regression, lapply

I would like to know how I can loop a regression n times, and in each time with a different set of variables, extract a `data.frame` where each column is a regression and each row represent a variable.

In my case I have a `data.frame` of:

```
dt_deals <- data.frame(Premium=c(1,3,4,5),Liquidity=c(0.2,0.3,1.5,0.8),Leverage=c(1,3,0.5,0.7))
```

But I have another explanatory dummy variable called `hubris`, that is the product of a binomial distribution, with 0.25 of mean. Like that:

```
n <- 10 
hubris_dataset <- data.frame(replicate(n, rbinom(4,1,0.25))
```

In this sense, what I need is to make n simulation of `hubris`, so I can, make n regression each one with a different set of random binomial distribution and the output of each distribution needs to be put in a `data.frame`
So far I could reach this:

```
# define n as the number of simulations i want
n=10
# define beta as a data.frame to put every coefficient from the lm regression
beta=NULL

for(i in 1:n) {
  dt_deals2 <- dt_deals
  beta[[i]] <- coef(lm(dt_deals$Premium ~ dt_deals$Liquidity + dt_deals$Leverage + hubris_dataset[,i], data=dt_deals2))
  beta <- cbind(reg$coefficients)
}
```

But this way it only generate the first set of coefficient, and doesn't make another ten columns for the `data.frame`.

Comment: just use `replicate`

Comment: Your code is convoluted and confusing. Your for loop is assigning the coefficient values to `beta[[i]]`. The double bracket subset is used for `list` objects not vectors as you created with `beta=NULL`.

Comment: You also write over everything with `beta <- cbind(reg$coefficients)`. So you are assigning values in `beta[[i]] <- ` then you are over-writing it all in the next line.

Comment: Per `beta<-cbind(reg$coefficients)` you overwrite the value of `beta`. Delete this line and initiate `beta <- list()` (not `beta <- NULL`). A more elegant solution without explicit loop is `beta <- sapply(1:n, function(i) coef(...))`

Comment: What ten columns are you missing?

Comment: @jogo thank you very much! I changed the object beta to list() and replaced the for-loop code to sapply and it did great.


    beta<-sapply(1:n, function(i) coef(lm(Premium ~ Liquidity +Leverage+ hubris_dataset[,i], data=dt_deals2)))

Answer (score 1):

@jogo give an idea to change the for-loop method and use sapply, and change the object beta to list(). This was the result:

```
beta <- sapply(1:n, function(i) coef(lm(Premium ~ Liquidity +Leverage+ hubris_dataset[,i], data=dt_deals2)))
```

And it worked